# Trouble installing guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

How do I install Guzzle, I've tried several different methods but failed and I've read their guides and etc. I don't have SSH access, so keep that in mind.

Comment: The best way is to use Composer, and just add it to your composer.json file. Bring it into your local project - worry about sending all the files to your host later on.

Comment: You can download it here: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/releases and upload it with FTP? For more information see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/guzzle/IfYceJx6HLM